# Type-safe difference lists

Tags: haskell, types

A common idiom in Haskell, difference lists, is to represent a list `xs` as the value `(xs ++)`. Then `(.)` becomes "`(++)`" and `id` becomes "`[]`" (in fact this works for any monoid or category). Since we can compose functions in constant time, this gives us a nice way to efficiently build up lists by appending.

Unfortunately the type `[a] -> [a]` is way bigger than the type of functions of the form `(xs ++)` -- most functions on lists do something other than prepend to their argument.

One approach around this (as used in `dlist`) is to make a special `DList` type with a smart constructor. Another approach (as used in `ShowS`) is to not enforce the constraint anywhere and hope for the best. But is there a nice way of keeping all the desired properties of difference lists while using a type that's exactly the right size?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes!

We can view `[a]` as a free monad instance `Free ((,) a) ()`.

Thus we can apply the scheme described by Edward Kmett in [Free Monads for Less](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/free-monads-for-less-2/).

The type we'll get is

```
newtype F a = F { runF :: forall r. (() -> r) -> ((a, r) -> r) -> r }
```

or simply

```
newtype F a = F { runF :: forall r. r -> (a -> r -> r) -> r }
```

So `runF` is nothing else than the `foldr` function for our list!

This is called the [Boehm-Berarducci encoding](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/Boehm-Berarducci.html) and it's isomorphic to the original data type (list) — so this is as small as you can possibly get.

---

Will Ness says:

> So this type is still too "wide", it allows more than just prefixing - doesn't constrain the g function argument.

If I understood his argument correctly, he points out that you can apply the `foldr` (or `runF`) function to something different from `[]` and `(:)`.

But I never claimed that you can use `foldr`-encoding only for concatenation. Indeed, as this name implies, you can use it to calculate *any* fold — and that's what Will Ness demonstrated.

It may become more clear if you forget for a moment that there's one true list type, `[a]`. There may be lots of list types — e.g. I can define one by

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

It's be different from, but isomorphic to `[a]`.

The `foldr`-encoding above is just yet another encoding of lists, like `List a` or `[a]`. It is also isomorphic to `[a]`, as evidenced by functions `\l -> F (\a f -> foldr a f l)` and `\x -> runF [] (:)` and the fact that their compositions (in either order) is identity. But you are not obliged to convert to `[a]` — you can convert to `List` directly, using `\x -> runF x Nil Cons`.

The important point is that `F a` doesn't contain an element that is not the `foldr` functions for some list — nor does it contain an element that is the `foldr` functions for more than one list (obviously).

Thus, it doesn't contain too few or too many elements — it contains precisely as many elements as needed to exactly represent all lists.

This is not true of the difference list encoding — for example, the `reverse` function is not an append operation for any list.

Comment: There is a pleasantly readable discussion of this type (more in the form `Folding a = F {runF :: forall r. (Maybe (a,r) -> r) -> r}` -- and some similar types, from the point of view of competing fusion rules -- short cut fusion, stream fusion -- in Roman Leshchinskiy's [Squinting at fusion](http://unlines.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/squinting-at-fusion/)

Comment: How is this a "Yes!"? With `empty = F (\r g->r)` and `singleton x = F (\r g-> g x r)` I can still call `runF (singleton 2) [1] (\a r->[a])` ==> `[2]` and `runF (singleton 4) [3,2,1] (\a r->a:reverse r)` ==> `[4,1,2,3]`. So this type is still too "wide", it allows more than just prefixing - doesn't constrain the `g` function argument.  Where am I mistaken?

Comment: @WillNess: I updated my answer, hopefully that answers your question now.

Comment: I understand that `F a` represents `[a]`; I thought the question was about representing `([a] ++)`. With `F` (http://hpaste.org/77691) I can say `runF (fromList [1..3]) [11..14] (const reverse)` as well as `runF (fromList [1..3]) [11..14] (:)`. *I* need to enforce *myself* to use the latter, in order to represent the prefixing. Of course the former can be seen as another "kind" of "prefixing", so maybe that's all just semantics.